# What is the way to do the following in C?

Tags: c, file, pointers

I want to save a location in file, and later restore the file pointer to the saved location.

```
 FILE *save = fp;

//perform operations on file fp...  

..
..

//restore to previously saved location

fp = save;
```

I tried the above method, but it does not work.

Comment: Both `save` and `fp` points to the same location, that is why. Try having two `FILE` pointers.

Comment: As well as `fseek()` and `ftell()`, there is also `fgetpos()` and `fsetpos()` too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Positioning.html) for information about the `ftell` and `fseek` functions. These will allow you to retrieve and set the position of the file pointer, respectively.

```
long int originalPos = ftell(fp);
// do stuff with file
fseek(fp, originalPos, SEEK_SET);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 fp variables? Use the one you didn't perform actions on to restore?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `fseek` and `ftell`.  `long int pos = ftell(fp);` to get the current position, and `fseek(fp, pos, SEEK_SET);` to return to that point.

Relevant man page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftell